# Is Azure AD B2C a good fit for public facing web application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a scenario where I want my Web Application front end to be able to Signup and sign in users and then an admin to be able to assign users to some pre defined roles.

I was able to do that by registering the application in Azure AD and introducing the app roles in App's Manifest file and later I assigned few users to their appropriate roles.

Then I implemented default signupIn flow but the assigned roles are not part of the returned claims in idToken.

idea was to send these roles info in tokens to the Backend api where [Authorize, Role="xxx"] attribute will take care of it.

is there any other solution to this kind of a scenario that I am missing ?

in the documentation is see it mentions "App Role" link on the left nav
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps
but i don't see any such link on left. Am i missing something ?

Comment: There are configuration settings in the app registration setup, not sure if its in the user flow, but it defines which claims are returned to the application.  It's near the settings where you can decide if the user gets and auth token / access_token.  I will find it and send a link / screenshot

Comment: thankyou so much. i am desperately waiting for an answer . looking for it for many hours.

Comment: I do not see it there anymore like in the MS DOCS article you shared.  I think things may have changed.  There is a place to add custom claims for your User Flow... here is the link: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_B2CAdmin/TenantManagementMenuBlade/userJourneys

Comment: not 100% sure that i am saying it right but that  might be the reason. instead of registering my apps in my primary Azure account i created a new Azure AD B2C Tenant and registered my apps there. in that tenant i dont have, i guess, right privileges so iu dont see things like "App Roles" and "Token Customization" on left side nav. but on my main account's Azure AD i can see those.

Answer (score 1):

finally figured it out. i was not understanding the difference between Azure ad Tenant and Azure AD B2C tenant. when i registered my app in azure ad tenant , created app roles form UI and assigned users some roles after going from Enterprise app,
i was able to see thoes roles in returned token.